# asp:Linkbutton enables but is not clickable

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

I don't know if this is a bug or whatever, but how can I call the event in the code-behind after enabling the linkbutton?

This is my linkbutton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnStartImportNow" runat="server" OnClick="btnStartImportNow_Click" Enabled="false">
    <div class="css_action_item_enabled" style="float: right;">
    <div class="css_action_item_icon_add">
    </div>
    <span class="css_action_link">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStartImport">
    </asp:Label>
    </span>
    </div>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now I have a javascript with this rule:

```
document.getElementById(clientId + "_btnStartImportNow").disabled = false;
```

Well the button enables, but I cannot click the button... What is wrong?!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the postback event is not attached to the link because the link was rendered as disabled... If you look at the html code, is there an onclick event?

Comment: Yep, im banking on that too. ASP.NET will not create the `_doPostback` event for server-side controls if they are not visible. Try setting them to hidden *after* the page has loaded (ie on window.load / docready)

Comment: correct, the onclick event isn't registered... If I add the onclick with document.getElementById(clientId + "_btnStartImportNow").setAttribute("OnClick", "btnStartImportNow_Click"); then I get the message when I click it that btnStartImportNow_Click is undefined...

Comment: Thanks!! I managed to fix it with the window.load like RPN1984 told me.. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the disabled property in the window.load so the _doPostback gets registered before the button gets disabled which causes the _doPostback to skip his registration :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that server side.
Remove the **Enabled="False"** from the tag and add this line in the Page_Load event instead:

```
btnStartImportNow.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Client side solution is good but has several downside:

1. Won't work when user disabled scripting in the browser
2. Cross browser issues